# How to classify all $\theta$-stable Cartan sub algebras?

Tags: lie-algebras

Let $G$ be a linear connected semisimple Lie group, $\mathfrak g$ its Lie algebra.
With respect to the Cartan involution
$$
\theta:X\mapsto -\overline{X}^t,
$$
one has $\mathfrak{g}=\mathfrak{k}\oplus \mathfrak{p}$.

Let $\mathfrak{a}$ be a maximal abelian subspace of $\mathfrak p$, $\mathfrak{t}$ a maximal abelian subspace of $\mathfrak{m}=C_\mathfrak{k}(\mathfrak a)$. Then 
$$\mathfrak{h}_r=\mathfrak{a}\oplus \mathfrak{t}$$ is a $\theta$-stable Cartan subalgebra with maxinum real rank.

Let $\mathfrak{t_0}$ be a maximal abelian subspace of $\mathfrak k$. Then 
$$\mathfrak h_1=C_\mathfrak{g}(\mathfrak{t}_0)=\mathfrak t_0\oplus C_\mathfrak{p}(\mathfrak{t}_0)$$
is the $\theta$-stable Cartan subalgebra with minumun real rank.

How to classify other $\theta$-stabl Cartan subalgebras?

Comment: I'm not sure if this addresses the question, but using Cayley transforms associated with real or imaginary non-compact roots, one can obtain all $\theta$-stable Cartan subalgebras of $\mathfrak{g}$, starting from any given one. A possible reference could be section 7 of chapter VI in the book 
A. W. Knapp, 'Lie groups beyond an introduction', 2nd ed., Birkhäuser, 2002